# Description of Stack Overflow em Português should be in Portuguese

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, localization

The Description of [Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/) in the **More Stack Exchange Communities** of the Stack Exchange Button is currently written in English. I think it should be written in Portuguese.

[image]

Comment: I don't really agree. The site list is for English speakers so we can know what each site is about. Only when *inside* the site everything indeed should be in Portuguese. That said, the description should be different, e.g. "Português version of Stack Overflow".

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah maybe, but the name of the site is also in Portoguese.

Comment: Off topic: I think Stack Overflow em Portugues is the first *themed* beta site.

Comment: @hims056 - pretty sure http://ux.stackexchange.com/ got it's theme while it was still beta too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At some point, likely in the distant past, this was completed:

[image: "Stack Overflow em Portugues" description is now written in Portuguese]